# Is the current obtained using Ohm's law that which passes through the resistor or that which passes through the circuit?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Shouldn't the current passing through a resistor be lesser than that which passes through a circuit?

My understanding is that since Current = Charges/Time. If there exists a resistance to the flow of charges, then that must mean the charges slow down, meaning that more time is required to pass through a point. So, the current should then decrease. But, since this opposition to the flow of charges doesn't exist in the ENTIRE circuit, it should really only decrease the current in the resistor, right?

Am I confusing the resistance of the resistor with the resistance of the wire? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks a bunch for lending me some of your time :D

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't the current passing through a resistor be lesser than that which passes through a circuit?

No. If it were less, charge would accumulate at the point the current enters the resistor.

Comment: Current = Charges/time. The time factor increases to pass through a certain point. So, the current should decrease while passing THROUGH the resistor, but the current at the input and the output of the resistor, will, however, remain the same.

Comment: It doesn’t work that way. If the current is 3 amperes, it means 3 coulombs pass each cross-section per second, whether the cross-section is in the wire or in the resistor.

Comment: Doesn't a resistor provide a resistance to the flow of charge? Won't that slow down the charge? Won't that reduce current?

Comment: It reduces the current in the entire circuit compared to what it would be if the resistor weren’t there.

Comment: I would love to know WHY that happens! I've been so confused about this. The resistance to the flow of charge only exists in the resistor, right? So, why would the current be reduced in the entire circuit and not just the resistor? The resistance isn't met by the current in the entire circuit. For instance, take a series combination of resistors. The current would remain constant no matter how many resistors/of what magnitude are connected, however, it's only reduced whilst flowing INSIDE the resistor.

Comment: You could ask that as a new question.

Comment: But consider this analogy. Imagine you are pulling a rope over some pulleys, and *one* of them is sticky and resists turning.

Comment: Well, since we normally associate the concepts of electricity with water in a pipe, why not consider this analogy: A pipe has two open ends, of equal cross-sectional areas. However, in the middle, the pipe gets a bit narrow as compared to both ends. The amount of water passing through the narrow bit should be lesser than that before or after it. That narrow bit of the pipe is the resistance and water is the current.

Comment: The analogy is fine. But isn’t it obvious that you can’t have 3 gallons per second passing through the wide pipe and 2 gallons per second passing through the narrow pipe? Where would the other one gallon per second go? I’m done because comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: The 1 gallon isn't going anywhere. It just takes longer for the 3 gallons to travel through the narrow pipe as compared to the wider pipe.

Comment: You seem very confident in your knowledge. You are allowed to write an answer to your own question. Why not do so, and explain that the current in the resister is reduced? Goodbye.

Comment: still waters run deep.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to understand your part of the explanation.. as I've said before, I'm really confused about this. 

Thanks a lot for your time, though! Really appreciate you helping me out!!

Comment: @G.Smith I think I'm starting to understand more of what you've been trying to say! A fellow just told me: Current has to be the same everywhere in a series circuit. This includes inside the resistor (which is a part of the circuit). If the current were not the same everywhere, then charge would be piling up somewhere. But a pile up of charge would lead to an electric field that would tend to get the charge moving again, smoothing out the current. So current is not less inside a resistor than outside. Instead, current decreases uniformly everywhere in the circuit when a resistor is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you compare it with the flow of water in a pipe instead of the batterie take a pump. The resistor is a very narrow part of the pipe compared to the rest of the water circuit. Now since this narrow resistor is in the circuit less water per second can flow thru  than without so the narrow part determines the water current , but its less in all the parts of the tubes. In the narrow part it will flow faster, since the same amount must pass the a smaller area, but the current here liters/second is everywhere the same, since where els should the water coming to the narrow part stay if not flown the, an the water leaving the narrow will flow back to the pump.
Same with electric current, the resistor regulates how mach charge can pass an area per second, the speed of the charge in the resistor will be higher thats why the resistor gets hot, but all the charges which go in  area must get out .

Comment: So, the resistor only regulates how many charges will pass through the RESISTOR ITSELF and not through the circuit, right?

Comment: No, I tried ti emphasize, that the resistor regulates how many charges go thru any part of the circuit.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it even more now. The water analogy is confusing me but I think I've cleared it in the comment of Mr. G. Smith's answer.